# PHP str_replace( ) won't work in user defined function

Tags: php, user-defined-functions, str-replace

When I try to make a user defined function using str_replace it has no effect. Components of the same code work perfectly when not in a user defined function. The following shows a simple representation of my problem.

```
<?php
function replacelist($thetext) {
    $seachfor = array("crackers","soup");
    $replacewith = array("shapes","stew");
    $newtext = str_replace($searchfor, $replacewith, $thetext);
    return $newtext." - plus some test text";
    }
?>


<?php
$mytext="Animal crackers in my soup";

$newphrase = replacelist($mytext);

echo $newphrase;
?>
```

The above results in

> **Animal crackers in my soup - plus some test text**

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks David

Comment: Activate error reporting! It'll tell you that you've typo'd your variable name.

Comment: TYPO - $seachfor and $searchfor

Comment: Generally it is a good idea to copy/paste your variables to avoid misspellings.

Comment: @Koninos Or use a decent IDE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spell `$seachfor` correctly and it will work.

Comment: That's embarassing. I have my more complex version working now.  - thanks very much for your help